# How to enable Redux Devtools?

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-chrome-extension, react-redux

I am following tutorial on React and instructor install an extension on Chrome, the **Redux Devtools**. In my case i am wondering why my extension seems to be **inactive (in color gray)**. In my chrome extension settings, it is **On**, site access is set **On all sites**, Allow access to file URLs
 is on but when i view my Redux tab, it shows:

`No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions.`

On the **.js** file, there is a declaration something like this:

```
const ReactReduxDevTools = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__();
let store;
if(window.navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome") && ReactReduxDevTools){
 store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(...middleware), 
            ReactReduxDevTools)
    );
}else{
...
}
```

What could be the problem? Compatibility with the Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux'

import reducers from './reducers';


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware()))


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: This answer means that probably @Anirudh Lou   have missed to "use" the store, as  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,

Answer (score 2):

It only works when it detects a store on the application you are running. It makes sense since there is nothing to be shown.

Start an application with Redux correctly wired up and it will appear colored and will have very useful information.

EDIT:

I think I found it. Check the code correction. The `compose` method must be raplace if a `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` exists.

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

let store;

store = createStore(
          rootReducer,
          initialState,
          composeEnhancers(
            applyMiddleware(...middleware)
        );
```

No `if` statements

Comment: The store has to be configured to talk to the extension.  Please see [the Redux docs page on "Configuring Your Store"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store).  Also, [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) automatically configures the devtools extension setup for you.

Answer (score 1):

`@reduxjs/toolkit` comes with devtools already built in (which should strongly be considered when using redux). Just add the flag:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: enableBatching(
    combineReducers({
      appState: stateSlice.reducer,
    })
  ),
  devTools: true // set to `true` if dev mode, i.e. import.meta.env.DEV for vite
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to apply if you have multiple middlewares.

1. Install extension using npm or yarn

```
npm install --save redux-devtools-extension
```

2. Apply to store.js or wherever your store is initialized

```js
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const middlewares = [] //put your middleware over here

export const store = createStore(Reducer,composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: enableBatching(
    combineReducers({
      appState: stateSlice.reducer,
    })
  ),
  devTools: true // set to `true` if dev mode, i.e. import.meta.env.DEV for vite
});
```

- List item