# Cannot access the property of an object - getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Now i have seen the other questions of this type and tried the solutions and it didnt work.

So now whats the problem?

Im using redux dispatching same data, an object with a label and userID, im then putting that data in a const pharmas with useSelector, when i log the const i get an object in the console containing the dispatched data and that is fine.

Now the problem is when i try to log pharmas.userID i get undefined for some reason.

Heres how it looks like when i log it normally [console.log(pharmas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcyei.png) and this is[JSON.stringify(pharmas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4FLq.png)

Can someone please explain why am i getting [cannot read property of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTe6l.png)

and what can i do to extract userID since i need it to filter out some data?

Thanks in advance!

Heres the code, getting data and and logging it

```js
const pharmas = useSelector ((state) => state.pharmacies.filteredPharmacies)

console.log('pharmas', pharmas)
```

Dispatching the data:

```js
const handleOnChange = (value) => {
 dispatch(getPharmacie(value))
 
 console.log('HERE',value)
};
```

Heres what the "value" looks like in the console [Exactly like i get it in pharmas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtKVx.png):

heres the reducer:

```
export function pharmacies(
  state = { pharmacies: [], selectedPharmacies: [], filterPharmacies: [] },
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PHARMACIES_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        pharmacies: action.payload,
    };
    case SET_PHARMACIE:
      return{
        ...state,
        filterPharmacies: action.payload,
    }
    case GET_PHARMACIE:
     return{
      ...state,
      filteredPharmacies: action.payload,
     }
    case SET_PHARMACIES:
```

Using GET_PHARMACIE case:

But when i console.log(pharmas.userID) i get the error undefined.

Heres the GET_PHARMACIE in store from redux extension [state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trzYh.png)

Comment: Hi ! You can certainly notice on the questions you have read that people share (or are asked to share) some test data and a sample code to reproduce the issue. This way, people are able to help you :)

Comment: Jerry Maguire would say "show me the code!"

Comment: It’s likely that your render code is running prior to the data being available.  Your render code should be able to handle situations where the data isn’t there yet (display “loading…” or similar).  this is just a guess since you haven’t posted any code - please do.

Comment: Probably you didnot provide the initial state in your redux reducer correctly

Comment: Install Redux firefox/chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en
And don't forget to enable dev options on your redux implementation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838038/how-to-enable-redux-devtools

this is really usefull to debug, once installed, open redux tab and click "state" to see all your store

Comment: @KevinGilbert i've added the screen shot in the question, the state of the GET_PHARMACIES filteredPharmacies has label and userID  so i should be able to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look like you're setting an empty payload on `GET_PHARMACIE`
you don't need to dispatch anything when retrieving data in the store.

One thing that I really like to do in my projects is to systematically create a custom hook for each of my "module". Here is how I would deal with that :

`usePharmas` : returns all pharma
`usePharmasActions` : return each actions availables

inside your hook, you only expose data wrapped in `useSelector` and actions wrapped with `useDispatch`.

that code will be easier to maintain and to test.

Comment: But im reading it from pharmas when i log the whole thing, should i change filteredPharmacies to filterPharmacies in reducer under GET_PHARMACIE?

Comment: oh god, it appear the issue was in the reducer after all, i just didnt notice i used an empty payload god, thank you!!

Comment: np, you could also use a memoized selector for filtered data